# How to get currently used Artisan console command name in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

**Problem / What I've tried:**

Getting the currently used controller and action in Laravel 5 is easy (but not as easy as it should be), however I'm stuck with getting the currently used artisan console command.

To fetch the controller name I do this:

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->match(Request::capture());
$listAction = explode('\\', $route->getActionName());
$rawAction = end($listAction);
// controller name and action in a simple array
$controllerAndAction = explode('@', $rawAction);
```

But when calling from a console action, it always returns the default index controller's name ("IndexController" or so in Laravel). Does anybody know how to make this ?

By the way I've also worked throught `Request::capture()` but this still gives no info about the command.

Comment: `But when calling from a console action, it always returns the default index controller's name ` How do you call that from command line?

Comment: @TheAlpha via *php artisan mycommand*

Comment: What do you actually need to know about your Command? its name?

Comment: Thers is no request when you are running from console. The request is available only when you use `Http` Kernel.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to just to look at the arguments specified on the command line:

```
if (array_get(request()->server(), 'argv.1') === 'cache:clear') {
    // do things
}
```

Yes, you can use `$_SERVER` directly, but I like to use the helper functions or the Facades, as those will give you the current data.
I go from the assumption that - during unit tests - the superglobals might not always reflect the currently tested request.

By the way: Obviously can also do `array_get(request()->server('argv'), '1')` or something alike. (`request()->server('argv.1')` doesnt work at this point). Or use `\Request::server()`. Depends on what you like most.

Answer (score 4):

As per the `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` class, the method to return the name of the command (eg. `my:command`) is:

```
$this->getName();
```

You should use it from within an Artisan command extending `Illuminate\Console\Command` (default on Artisan commands).

Remember that it will return only the command name and not the available parameters (eg. for the command signature `my:command {--with-params=}` it will only return `my:command`).

Answer (score -2):

Reflection might be of help? Try this:

```
$var = new \ReflectionClass($this);
dd($var);
```

Comment: How does this help the OP get the Artisan command name?! If you really think this should be the accepted answer, please provide more insight on how he will be able to achieve the objective.